# Routine matrix functions in ff

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, bigdata, ff

I am new to dealing with big matrices in R. I am trying to learn with `ff`.
I can create large `ff` matrices `ffsdist1` and `ffsdist2` as follows.

```
library(stringdist)
library(babynames)
library(ff)

d <- babynames
sdist1 <- stringdistmatrix(d$name[1:1000], d$name[1:2500], method="lv", useBytes = T)
sdist2 <- stringdistmatrix(d$name[1001:2000], d$name[1:2500], method="lv", useBytes = T)
```

I can create the ff matrices as follows

```
ffsdist1 <- ff(sdist1, dim=dim(sdist1))
ffsdist2 <- ff(sdist2, dim=dim(sdist2))
```

I would like to replicate the following operations on `sdist1` and `sdist2` in the `ff` matrices.

#### 1. `rbind()`

```
sdist <- rbind(sdist1, sdist2)
```

#### 2. Replace parts using `[`

```
sdist1[sdist1 > 0] <- Inf
```

#### 3. Extract parts using`[`

```
ind1 <- grepl("\\bA", d$name[1:1000])
ind2 <- grepl("a\\b", d$name[1:1000])
sdist[ind1 & ind2]
```

and

```
sdist[,which(ind1)]
```

#### 4. Add two matrices

```
sdistsum <- sdist1 + sdist2
```

#### 5. Get transpose

```
tsdist1 <- t(sdist1)
```

Is this correct

```
tffsdist1 <- t(ffsdist1)
```

#### 6. Use `apply`

```
apply(sdist, 1,
      function(x) paste(as.character(unlist(d$name[x <= 3])),
                        collapse=", "))
```

How to do this using `ff` package in `R`?